# set which display on which monitor in unity

Tags: unity

I'm working on a project that has multi screen to show environment. the question is options not working when there is multi screen. for example in single screen you can set which screen shows the game but it seems there is not such option.

how can I set which display or which camera get displayed on which monitor in script? for example: camera display 1 to screen 2 and....?

thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the target display of any camera with the `TargetDisplay` propriety of the `Camera` component.

Via Inspector:

[image]

Via Script:

```
Camera camera;

void Awake() {
    camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
}

void CameraTargetDisplay (int target) {
    camera.targetDisplay = target;
}
```

`target` is equal to the display index in the `Display.displays` array.